# Pip cannot install packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I was trying to install  the `requests` module through pip, I typed `pip install requests`, and while installing it ran into this error:

```
Installing collected packages: certifi, urllib3, idna, chardet, requests
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python37-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\certifi'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

When I ran IDLE, I typed `import requests`, but it said that no module exists.
How do you fix this?

Python Version: 3.7.0

Comment: Did you try `pip install requests --user`?

Comment: "How do you fix this?" – Did you try reading the error message and following what it says how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyforms library: WinError5 Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840725/pyforms-library-winerror5-access-is-denied)